# error on line 2 at column 8: error parsing attribute name ,sitemap.xml file in react app public folder

Tags: reactjs, xml, free, sitemap, public-folders

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">

https://www.metalaunch.io/

2022-07-28T04:46:14+00:00

1.00

https://www.metalaunch.io/assets/files/terms-of-use.pdf

2022-07-05T15:39:20+00:00

0.80

https://www.metalaunch.io/assets/files/privacy-policy.pdf

2022-07-05T15:39:20+00:00

0.80

https://app.metalaunch.io

2022-07-05T15:39:20+00:00

0.80

https://stake.metalaunch.io

2022-07-05T15:39:20+00:00

0.80